# Proper Windows Forms multi screen program

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to build a rather simple Windows Application for the employees that process our payroll (currently it's a vbscript/terminal combination).  The logic is mostly worked out, but I'm trying to find out what the best way build a Windows Forms application that has multiple screens (login/etc).  I've been using the `TabControl` container for this, but just wasn't sure if this was correct...or 'common'.

If this is what is normally done are the contents of the tabs generally made up of `User Control` object or are they just filled with different layouts on the tab?

I doubt I need much in the way of help on the coding side, but more the "how a gui" is normally laid out in the visual designer.

EDIT: Just to provide a basis of the screens that I'm needing to build.  I'm currently planning on having a Login Screen and the three screens that guide the user through processing two different types of payroll and then certain accounts receivables work.  Primarily I will have two user types.  The ones that process payroll and the ones that do accounts receivable work.  I'm wanting to make this easily expandable so that as I build in more functionality it's not a major pain to add screens and limit who can see them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resources for windows form design and increased usability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189286/resources-for-windows-form-design-and-increased-usability). Besides that, this question is too broad to even begin answering it.

Comment: @GertArnold it's broad due to no current base to have a specific code related question.  My question is how are the UI's generally built.  Not a question of how the UI should look/function.  I can finagle my way through doing that now.  I'm just trying to make sure I'm doing it properly (if there is a current convention to current control usage).  If there is some more information that I can provide to make the question to your liking please let me know.  I have no problem doing the work needed to help get a question answered. I guess I just don't know what to provide at the moment.

Comment: It depends, simply layout the controls on the tab if that makes sense. If you find you are reusing controls on tab pages then user User Controls.

Comment: I think, for your needs, you should use MDI forms instead of tabcontrols. But maybe I'm misunderstanding your needs.

Comment: @trippino I will actually update the question with an answer.  I ended up integrating with our AD Server to add tabs based on what group a user is in.  Each tab simply has a `UserControl` on it that I've made that contains the logic and layout.  While this may not be 100% correct it does remove any of the responsibilities from the primary "form" other then to add the different `UserControls` that are displayed through the use of a `TabControl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is removing the "Login Screen" as hinted to in the question.  Instead of a Login Screen and the corresponding logic being required I ended up doing integration with our Active Directory Server.

Once this integration was done I simply design the Screens as `UserControl` elements and then add each one to a tab based on if the user is in a specific group or not.

Doing this solved my main concern of having a heavy main form containing logic.  Now the only logic in the main form is whether or not to add a tab based on Active Directory groups.